# RAID/AHCI Trouble installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on Dell laptop

Tags: dual-boot, windows, raid, ahci

I need help installing Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 7577.

Note, this laptop comes with windows 10 pre-installed on a SSD.

I tried installing Ubuntu 17.10 using a USB device.
But as I went on with the installation it said that it didn't recognize any operating systems on my computer. It also said that I was force booting into UEFI mode and it would cause problems with the dual-boot also.

I researched and found that if I switched from RAID to AHCI the Ubuntu installation would finally recognize windows and give me the option to install alongside it.

Now the problem is, if I switch to AHCI then I cannot boot into Windows anymore.

How do I solve this? please.

I ran this:
export LC_MESSAGES=POSIX; sudo lsblk -f; sudo lshw -C storage

```
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                                  /rofs
sda                                                              
├─sda1                                                           
└─sda2 ntfs     buttpicss   7C6C3BE36C3B96BC                     
sdb                                                              
└─sdb1 vfat     UBUNTU 17_1 EE01-1D54                            /cdrom
  *-usb:1                   
       description: Mass storage device
       product: USB Flash Drive
       vendor: Lexar
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: scsi2
       version: 1.02
       serial: 2013092608152923494A
       capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-storage
       description: RAID bus controller
       product: 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 17
       bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
       version: 31
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: storage msix pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:dd3a0000-dd3a7fff memory:dd3b9000-dd3b90ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:dd300000-dd37ffff
  *-scsi
       physical id: 1
       logical name: scsi1
       capabilities: emulated
```

Comment: You need to install AHCI drivers in Windows before switching.

Comment: Could you please put the storage controller in RAID mode, boot a live system (select "Try Ubuntu" in the boot menu of the Ubuntu installation medium), open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), run `export LC_MESSAGES=POSIX; sudo lsblk -f; sudo lshw -C storage` and [edit] your question to include the output of the previous command sequence? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ok I added the sequence

Comment: Ubuntu recognises the storage device. Especially in fake RAID setups like yours the necessary subsystem may only be activated at a boot stage that the Ubuntu installer doesn't reach if you select it directly from the boot menu. Could you please try to start the Ubuntu installer from the live system? There's a good chance that it will recognise the storage drive and Windows installation this way. In general fake RAID setups are highly discouraged since they provide little practical advantages but involve a lot of hassle without proper driver support which the vendors rarely give to Linux.